# Erro ao carregar XML no Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, xml

Estou recebendo o erro abaixo ao carregar o XML usando o Laravel. Testei a importação com PHP puro e foi normalmente. Alguém tem ideia do que pode ser? Entendo que esse `&quot;` é aspas, mas não achei no XML.

```
simplexml_load_file(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity &quot;&quot;
```

Linha de código onde ocorre o erro:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($request->file('publicacao')); dd($xml
```

Comment: Segundo essa [pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21661593/simplexml-i-o-warning-failed-to-load-external-entity), o `simplexml_load_file()` espera um  `filename`, você está passando isso?

Comment: Sim. Tem outra alternativa a ele?

Comment: Posta o trecho de código completo, inclusive a linha que retorna esse erro, facilita pra entendermos melhor o problema.

Comment: $xml = simplexml_load_file($request->file('publicacao'));
dd($xml);
Uso laravel.

Comment: Coloque qual é o conteúdo de `$request->file('publicacao')`.

Comment: Não da. O arquivo é muito grande. Tentei colocar o conteúdo no PasteBin, mas excedeu o tamanho máximo.

Answer (score 1):

Até aonde entendo do `$request->file()` (retorna `Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile`) do Laravel não retorna uma string, inclusive se olhar na documentação vai notar que não existe nenhum `__toString` que deveria ser o minimo para o primeiro para retornar o caminho temporário do arquivo que esta fazendo upload, veja a documentação:

- https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Http/UploadedFile.html

Então provavelmente ao passar o valor para `simplexml_load_file` ele esta buscando um arquivo que não seja o arquivo correto, provavelmente o que esta entre `&quot;&quot;`, o que foi tentando passar foi um objeto, assim provavelmente:

```
object(Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile)#1 (0) {
}
```

É bem provável que os erros de *warning* estejam desligados ou ocultos, mas se estivesse ligado iria exibir algo como:

> PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_file() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, **object given**

A frase `object given` quer dizer que pegou um objeto, a frase anterior diz, o parametro 1 precisa ser um caminho valido, ou seja objeto não é caminho e nem string.

---

### Como ler o conteudo de `UploadedFile` do laravel

Provavelmente o correto seria usar `UploadedFile::get()` + `simplexml_load_string()`, assim:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($request->file('publicacao')->get());
dd($xml);
```